# Parse variable to class object

Tags: php, phpstorm

Following situation:

```
foreach ($this->allEvents as $event) {
    //use $event here
}
```

`allEvents` (array) stores several objects of `Event` class. 
Now I want that my IDE (PhpStorm) suggests me all methods that `$event` has. But unfortunately is does not know that `$event` is a Event object.

Is there any possibility to convert `$event` to an object of `Event` class?
Like type conversions in Java: `(Event) event`

Comment: What does $this->allEvents look like?

Comment: The problem probably lies somewhere in the way you annotated the property `allEvents` in your class. If you properly annotated allEvents or have a proper *getter* that has *return annotations* it should work. Make sure you are not just dynamically declaring the property because PHPStorm can't know whats going on then.

Comment: @Xatenev oh my gosh... I got it. I annotated it with (@ var array Event) but the proper version is @ var Event[].
Thank you so much :)

Comment: In Eclipse you can do  `\*@var $var Object*/` just before the foreach.  Not sure if PhpStorm has a similar method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Xatenev
The problem was a wrong annotation of $allEvents.
It has to look like

```
/**
 * @var Event[]
 */
private $allEvents = array();
```

so PhpStorm will understand it correctly as an array of Event objects

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `assert` inside `foreach` to make your IDE aware of the type of the variable:

```
foreach ($this->allEvents as $event) {
    assert($event instanceof Event);
    //use $event here
}
```

Assertions are not executed in the production code so there is no additional overhead of using them.